# Reference Request: Subgroup of free abelian group is free abelian

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, free-groups

I have the following **reference Question**, meaning that I search for a reference for the following statement: Let $F$ be a free abelian group of finite rank and $U$ be a subgroup. Then there is a basis $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ of $F$ and numbers $k_1, \dots, k_l \geq 1$ $(l \leq n)$ such that $\{k_1b_1, \dots, k_lb_l\}$ is a basis of $U$.

I found a proof in Langs Algebra book that subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian, but not this specific computation of the basis.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), and you can find [lots of references](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=smith+normal+form) on Google books.  In particular, [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=H1Zh6MP-9dYC) has exhaustive coverage of Smith normal form and all of its consequences.