# $H \leq \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_q^m$ implies that $\mathbb{Z}_q^n / H \cong \mathbb{Z}_q^{n-m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules

> Given a pair of positive integers $n,q$ and a subgroup $H \leq \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ such that $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_q^m$ for a positive
>   integer $m < n$ then show that 
>   $$  \mathbb{Z}_q^n / H \cong \mathbb{Z}_q^{n-m}.$$

This is a problem I came up with trying to generalize the trivial case when $q$ is a prime number (It is trivial because in this case a $\mathbb{Z}_q$- module is a vector space).

I actually found a proof but I believe it's way too long for such a statement so I'm not asking for hints or suggestions: my question is if somebody is able to find a better proof (even a sketch would be fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_i$ be the component vectors of $G=\mathbb{Z}_q^n$, which have $1$ in the $i$th place, and zero elsewhere.  Consider the generators of $H$; let's write one as
$$ h_1 = (a_1, \ldots, a_n) $$

This element has order $q$, so one of the components has order $q$: say $a_i$. Then
$$ \{h_1\}\bigcup \{e_j\mid j\neq i\}$$
is a generating set for $G$ of $n$ order-$q$ elements; there is thus an automorphism of $G$ sending $h_1$ to $e_i$. We can thus quotient out $e_1$, and induction on $m$ then shows $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}_q^{n-m}$.

**Edit**: The above only works for $q$ a prime power, but that ends up being enough. Because $G$ can be written as a direct product of its Sylow subgroups
$$ G = P_1\times P_2\times\cdots\times P_r $$
where each Sylow subgroup is the unique one in $G$.  Order considerations show
$$ H = (H\cap P_1)(H\cap P_2)\cdots(H\cap P_r) $$
and this product is direct since the factors have trivial intersection.

Thus
$$ G/H\cong P_1/(H\cap P_1)\times P_2/(H\cap P_2)\cdots $$
and these groups have the desired form by the first part of this answer.

Comment: Sadly, it's not true that one of the component of $h_1$ need to have order $q$. This only happens in the case when $q = p^k$. A basic counterexample is in $\mathbb{Z}^2_6$ the group $H = \langle (2,3) \rangle$. In particular there is no element in $H$ that satisfy your property (but still $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_q^1$)

Comment: Never the less i would please ask you to leave your answer here - just to point out how tricky this problem might be

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was thinking of $q$ as a prime power; I let the notation get the best of me!

Comment: should i edit it? cause in this special case your proof is correct

Comment: No I think it is OK to leave it. I actually think my approach can be salvaged. I just don't know how yet :)

Comment: @JayTuma: OK, I added the general case.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
Here is a slightly different viewpoint, which might clear up what's happening.

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}^n$ with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. Also let $K=qA$, which is a characteristic subgroup of $A$, since for $\phi\in\textrm{Aut}(A)$, $\phi(qa)=q\phi(a)\in K$.

So $G\cong A/K$; let $H$ be generated by $h_1,\ldots,h_m$, all of order $q$. Let $b_i$ be a preimage of $h_i$ in $A$ [it can just have the same coordinates of $h_i$]. Then $B=\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m\rangle$ maps to $H$.

Now [there exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1351281/265452) an automorphism $\phi\in\textrm{Aut}(A)$ sending $e_i$ to $f_i$, such that $b_i$ gets sent to $n_if_i$ for some integers $n_i$. We thus have the commutative diagram

\begin{CD}
A @>{\phi}>> A\\
@VVV @VVV \\
G @>>{\widetilde{\phi}}> G
\end{CD}

with $\widetilde{\phi}\in\textrm{Aut}(G)$. Note that we must have $\gcd(n_i,q)=1$ in order for $\widetilde{\phi}(h_i)$ to have order $q$. Thus we have 
\begin{align*}
G &=\langle \widetilde{f_1},\ldots,\widetilde{f_n}\rangle\\
\widetilde{\phi}(H) & =\langle n_1\widetilde{f_1},\ldots,n_m\widetilde{f_m}\rangle\\
&= \langle\widetilde{f_1},\ldots,\widetilde{f_m}\rangle
\end{align*}
 The problem is then trivial.

Comment: That is a bit more abstract approach and resemble somehow the fact that my question is equivalent to find a automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ that send $H$ to the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_q^{m} \times \{ e \}^{m-n}$ and this job is perfectly done by your function $\overline{\phi}$. Still i had no idea how to show the existance of such a function